# xde-desktop-portal crashing with SIGSEGV due to reading a NULL VMA, causing issues with Inkscape and Krita. Ubuntu 18.04.6

Tags: 18.04, inkscape

### The issue

Basically the title.

Lately both programs have began to take longer than usual to start, and, in the case of Inkscape, attempting to open a file will result in a crash.

Attempting to open a file with Inkscape from terminal gives the following result:

```
2023/01/06 21:08:46.782934 cmd_run.go:1055: WARNING: cannot start document portal: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.portal.Documents': timed out (service_start_timeout=120000ms)
Gtk-Message: 21:08:46.981: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 21:08:46.983: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.avail/53-monospace-lcd-filter.conf", line 10: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not work as expected

** (org.inkscape.Inkscape:9020): WARNING **: 21:09:12.680: Can't open file: /home/endelos/POSTER.svg (doesn't exist)

** (org.inkscape.Inkscape:9020): WARNING **: 21:09:12.685: Can't open file: /home/endelos/POSTER.svg (doesn't exist)
ink_file_open: '/home/endelos/POSTER.svg' cannot be opened!
InkscapeApplication::document_open: Failed to open: /home/endelos/POSTER.svg
ConcreteInkscapeApplication::on_open: failed to create document!
```

(please note that the file in question is very much not in /home, in fact it's in a subdirectory of /mnt, and both canberra-gtk-module and canberra-gtk3-module are installed in the system)

Attepmting to open Krita from terminal results in the same warnings regarding the document portal service and fontconfig before starting the program normally.

On the other hand, attempting to open a file on Inkscape from GUI, apart from taking longer than usual, results in the program becoming unresponsive and eventually triggering a crash report. In it, it basically explains that xde-desktop-portal crashed with SIGSEGV due to reading a NULL VMA.

### What I've tried

Reinstalling both programs as well as canberra-gtk-module, canberra-gtk3-module and their libcanberra counterparts as well as the titular xde-desktop-portal

### The question

How else could I go about discovering precisely what the problem is and how to solve it?